# How can I convert the built 'transaction' in XDR format?

Tags: transactions, javascript-sdk, xdr

Before I submit the transaction to the network I want to convert the 'transaction' in XDR format so that I can save it to database for future reference. I am using Stellar JS library. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `transaction` is a `Transaction` object then this will give you base64 encoded XDR:

```
transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR().toString("base64")
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. works. Another quick question, is the transaction hash and operation id generated before the transaction is submitted to the network or after?

Comment: Transaction hash can be generated before submitting to the network using `hash()` method. Operation ID (Horizon) can be generated once transaction is in the ledger.